# Разрешить доступ к файлу .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас доступ к файлам .php закрыт, т.е. если перейти по адресу одного из файлов .php, на сайте выдаст ошибку "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."

Нужно открыть доступ к одному файлу (pay_callback.php), но как не знаю

Содержимое .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

<Limit GET POST>
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Limit>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: У тебя RewriteRule запрещает .php

`RewriteRule pay_callback.php - [L]`

Comment: как вписать? не совсем понимаю 

`RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]`
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"`
`RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]`
`RewriteRule pay_callback.php - [L]`